# django-disqus with django 1.4.8

Tags: django, disqus

I'm receiving this error when I add disqus to the INSTALLED_APP:

```
Error: No module named urllib.parse
```

I tracked this down to the following line:

```
from django.utils.http import urlencode
from django.utils.six.moves.urllib.error import URLError
from django.utils.six.moves.urllib.request import (
    ProxyHandler,
    Request,
    urlopen,
    build_opener,
    install_opener
)
```

I know that six.moves is not included with django 1.4.8, is there any substitute?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Six](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/six) is an external library, which Django includes for convenience.

You could try installing `six` separately, and change the imports, for example change

```
from django.utils.six.moves.urllib.error import URLError
```

to

```
from six.moves.urllib.error import URLError
```